# how to simplify code to print all items in an array use one line code in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, lambda

I am trying to print out all items which >0  in array prime. I have

```
var k = prime.Where(n => n > 0);
foreach (var n in k)
    Console.Write(n);
```

I'm wondering how to simplify code into one line to avoid foreach statement to print everything out, like one line statement within blanket of Console.Write().
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ",prime.Where(n => n > 0)));
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I'm looking for,BTW,in items of efficiency, any differences between those two method?